# How can I resize my columns to fit their text width instead of all being the same width

Tags: html, css, css-tables

My table is fixed at 100%

```
table-layout:fixed
width:100%
```

Comment: (1) Show us your markup. (2) Don't use a table.

Comment: remove the `table-layout:fixed` ? fixed is specifically for ignoring the contents..

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `table-layout:fixed`.

Fixed is specifically for ignoring the contents..

look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/table-layout

Comment: The problem with that is the table is not the same size as the screen. it can be too small or too big for the screen, and i dont want scroll bars

Comment: @user: sounds like you've got a contradiction. You want the columns to fit their text lengths, but you don't want scroll bars (where? on the table? On the window?)

Comment: it doesn't work. the table over flow and requires a scroll bar. with fixed it stayed the same size as the window. but some cells that have a lot of text get cut while others with small characters have the same width even though they dont need it

Comment: are you using "nowrap" on the content of the cells? the 100% width should work to keep the table on the screen, if it's getting bigger than 100% it could mean an image or long word is forcing it over

Answer (score 1):

As answered already you would still have to remove `table-layout:fixed;`

but, as I think you are saying, this means the table column widths will likely be calculated by the first row "heading" widths, which is not always optimal what you might have to do, depending on how many columns is to use the the `col` & `colgroup` elements - **[reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4)** -  to set percentage widths for each column, that way your preferences will be used over the browsers "first pass".. make sure they total 100% and your table should be OK

a code example from you would help see if this is an option, or indeed if there's a better one!